# VBA, When I add row to table, then resize table, not picking up new value in pivot

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table. I put some data into the row beneath the table with vba(see sub formulas).

Then resize the table to include the newly added data(see ResizeListDyn)

The newly added data is now included in the old table.

But my pivot does not reflect the full new table when i refresh.
I have a pivot with the data source that is targeting this table.

[image]
[image]

```
Sub Formulas()

LastRow = WorksheetFunction.Max(Sheets("working").Cells(Rows.Count, "x").End(xlUp).Row)

With Worksheets("working")

    .Range("x" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=X" & LastRow & "+7"
    .Range("y" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(X" & LastRow + 1 & ",irworstcase!A:F,6,FALSE)"
    .Range("z" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(X" & LastRow + 1 & ",irworstcase!A:E,5,FALSE)"
    .Range("aa" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=+GETPIVOTDATA(""sum"",A$1,""businessDate"",$X" & LastRow + 1 & ",""substr"",AA$1,""ScenarioName"",$Y53)"
    .Range("ab" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=+GETPIVOTDATA(""sum"",B$1,""businessDate"",$X" & LastRow + 1 & ",""substr"",AB$1,""ScenarioName"",$Y53)"
    .Range("ac" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=+GETPIVOTDATA(""sum"",C$1,""businessDate"",$X" & LastRow + 1 & ",""substr"",AC$1,""ScenarioName"",$Y53)"
    .Range("ad" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=+GETPIVOTDATA(""sum"",D$1,""businessDate"",$X" & LastRow + 1 & ",""substr"",AD$1,""ScenarioName"",$Y53)"
    .Range("ae" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=+GETPIVOTDATA(""sum"",E$1,""businessDate"",$X" & LastRow + 1 & ",""substr"",AE$1,""ScenarioName"",$Y53)"
    .Range("af" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=+GETPIVOTDATA(""sum"",F$1,""businessDate"",$X" & LastRow + 1 & ",""substr"",AF$1,""ScenarioName"",$Y53)"
    .Range("ag" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=+GETPIVOTDATA(""sum"",G$1,""businessDate"",$X" & LastRow + 1 & ",""substr"",AG$1,""ScenarioName"",$Y53)"
    .Range("ah" & LastRow + 1).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(X" & LastRow + 1 & ",'pv01'!A:C,3,FALSE)"

    Call ResizeListDyn

End With

End Sub
Sub ResizeListDyn()

    Worksheets("working").Activate
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
    tbl.Resize tbl.Range.CurrentRegion

End Sub
```

Then when I refresh my pivot, it does not include the full new table.

Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Tables automatically resize themselves... that `LastRow` logic seems flawed. Why not use the `ListObject` API, since you're working with a table? Get the table e.g. `Set tbl = .ListObjects("Table1")` and then you can `Set newRow = tbl.ListRows.Add` and poof, you have a new row at the bottom of the table, and a `ListRow` object to play with - from there you can easily modify any of its cells, using a column index that you can either hard-code, or work out from the `ListObject`'s headers (and then a user swapping column order won't break anything).

Comment: Hi @MathieuGuindon would you be able to provide an answer? Are you saying I should just add a row instead of resizing? then after that run my formulas into this newly added table row?

Comment: I don't think `ResizeListDyn` is actually doing anything whatsoever. What you need is to refresh the pivot after updating the table. But yes, definitely leverage the `ListObject` API instead of hard-coding ranges and working out last rows.

Comment: your right i commented it out, doesnt do anything. Still when I refresh it doesnt pick up the newly added row, even though the newly added rough is the same table.

Comment: Try refreshing the pivot cache then :)

Comment: i did :( sigh not sure why it not pickingup new row! perhaps it is not really part of the table.

Comment: Also I should say, it looks like its coming in as a 'totals row'